# How to remove from manytomany field

Tags: python, django

I'm Django beginner. How do I remove a field from manytomany field.
Implementing my code I got 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'likes'

```
class Image(models.Model):
    imageuploader_profile=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    upload_image=models.ImageField()
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='image_likes')


def block_users(request, id)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    images = Image objects.filter(imageuploader_profile=user)
    if images.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        images.likes.remove(request.user)
```

Comment: `images` is not a single `Image` object, it is a colletion of `Image`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`images` is not a single `Image` object, it is a colletion of `Image`s, hence the queryset has no `likes` object. You can however remove the images from the other end:

```
def block_users(request, id)
    images = Image objects.filter(imageuploader_profile_id=id)
    request.user.image_likes.remove(*images)
    # …
```

> **Note**: A GET request is *not* supposed to have *side-effects*, hence removing
>   objects when a user makes a GET request, is not compliant with the HTTP
>   standard. Therefore it might be better to remove `likes` with a POST request.

Comment: How do I remove from manytomany field if it is not a request.user? I tried adding 'user.image_likes.remove(*images) 'below the 'request.user.image_like.......' when I click on the link, it removed both request.user and the user in admin. How do I remove only the request.user when clicked, or the user when other users click on the link. I mean how to remove for each users click